# BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, backup

I have a stored procedure, which performs a database backup for a specific database like this :

```
 ALTER PROC [dbo].[SP_Backup]
    @DataBaseName NVARCHAR(500) = NULL 
    @fullPath NVARCHAR(500) OUTPUT
AS 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @dbpath NVARCHAR(500);
            SELECT  @DataBaseName = DB_NAME()
            SELECT  @dbpath = physical_name
            FROM    sys.database_files
            WHERE   ( name = N'myDb' );
            SELECT  @fullPath = SUBSTRING(@dbpath, 0,
                                LEN(@dbpath) - CHARINDEX('\',
                                REVERSE(@dbpath)
                                + '\') + 1);
            SELECT  @fullPath = @fullPath + N'\Backups\' + @DataBaseName + N'.bak'
            BACKUP DATABASE @DataBaseName
        TO DISK = @fullPath;
    END;
```

The problem is, it does work on one server and does not work on another server (the servers are on same machines.-- sql 2008 r2). and i get the exception "BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally."

backup folders have same permission settings and are like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.Server1\MSSQL\DATA\Backup
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.Server2\MSSQL\DATA\Backup
```

and sql users are same too;

In the log file there are the following informations:

```
Error: 18204, Severity: 16, State: 1.
BackupDiskFile::CreateMedia: Backup device 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.Server2\MSSQL\DATA\Backups\myDb.bak' failed to create. Operating system error 3(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 1815).
Error: 3041, Severity: 16, State: 1.
BACKUP failed to complete the command BACKUP DATABASE myDb. Check the backup application log for detailed messages.
```

What could be the reason for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was a problem with create folder.

```
SELECT  @fullPath = @fullPath + N'\Backups\' + @DataBaseName + N'.bak'
```

server1 has "Backups" folder and sql can save backup on it, but there is not this folder on server2

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking the instance .

http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/157143-sql-server-2008-r2-multiple-instances-on-one-server